# How can I output a txt file, that has part of filename followed by path of file for all files in a folder, one line per file?

Tags: find, printf, basename

I have the following files

```
/folder/abc1.txt.gz
/folder/abc2.txt.gz
/folder/abc3.txt.gz
```

I would like to make a txt file with the following

```
abc1 /folder/abc1.txt.gz
abc2 /folder/abc2.txt.gz
abc3 /folder/abc3.txt.gz
```

I have used the following command

```
find /folder -name 'abc*.txt.gz' -type f -printf '%f %p\n' > out.txt
```

This will output:

```
abc1.txt.gz /folder/abc1.txt.gz
abc2.txt.gz /folder/abc2.txt.gz
abc3.txt.gz /folder/abc3.txt.gz
```

How can I have only the first part of the filename (without .txt.gz) folowed by the path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "part of the filename", and "path for all files in the folder".  Do you mean that when you find a matching file, you want to print all the other files in the same folder of the file? What if there are multiple matching files at the same folder? Could you provide a practical example of a sample directory/file tree and the exact expected output?

Comment: e.g I have the following files /folder1/abca.vcf.gz /folder1/prrt.vcf.gz /folder1/mefv.vcf.gz and I want a txt that will have abca /folder1/abca.vcf.gz, prrt /folder1/prrt.vcf.gz, mefv /folder1/mefv.vcf.gz one line for each file... hope this is more clear...

Comment: First, please edit your question and add the relevant details. Second, do you mean that you want to see the **filename without the extension**? If that's what you mean, you also need to specify that in the question. The question should be clear so that anyone that reads it understand your exact intention, without having to go through the comments for clarifications.

Comment: edited original to make it more clear..

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same extension, you could remove it this way:

```
find /folder -name 'abc*.txt.gz' -type f -printf '%f %p\n' |sed 's/\.txt.gz//'
```

This `sed` command will only remove the first occurrence of `.txt.gz`.

If you want to remove any extension:

```
find /folder -name 'abc*.txt.gz' -type f -printf '%f %p\n' |sed 's/\.[^[:space:]]* / /'
```

Assuming that there aren't any spaces in the extension itself, it will remove all the non-space characters after the first dot `.` until the first space.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful!

Comment: @christoforosgiatzakis If the answer helped you, you do not need to comment. It's usually expected to upvote the answer and accept it (press on the "V" sign below the votes of the answer)

Comment: Note that a file called `abc-01.txt-gzillion.txt.gz` would be listed as `abc-01illion.txt.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're seeking a solution using `basename`, and if we can assume that the `.txt.gz` suffix is constant across your set of files, and that you're using `bash`:

```
declare -a files

readarray -t files < <( find /folder -name '*.txt.gz' -type f )

for f in "${files[@]}"
do
        printf '%s %s\n' "$(basename "$f" '.txt.gz')" "$f"
done

$ test.sh
abc1 /folder/abc1.txt.gz
abc2 /folder/abc2.txt.gz
abc3 /folder/abc3.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

For shell bash:

```
find folder/ -name 'abc*.txt.gz' -exec bash -c ': ${0##*/}; echo ${_%%.*} $0' {} \;
```

`:` an empty command, but its argument `${0##*/}` is assigned to the `$_` internal variable (*the last argument to the previous simple command*).

Comment: Since you aren't quoting your variables in that in-line script, a file called `abc * .txt.gz` may cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `basename` to get rid of the directory path and the suffix from your files, then use `-print` to print the full pathname, and then combine the two with `paste`:

```bsh
find /folder -name 'abc*.txt.gz' -type f -exec basename {} .txt.gz \; -print |
paste - -
```

This would create lines of output that have two tab-delimited columns, where the first column would be the output of `basename` and the second would be the full pathname of the found file.  Would you want a single space as delimiter instead, then use `paste -d ' ' - -` in place of `paste - -`.

This relies on no name containing embedded newlines, and names containing the delimiter used by `paste` may also result in a list that is difficult to parse.